# Are there any teshuvot regarding the potato, when it was first introduced to Europe?

Tags: halacha, history, food

According to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_potato , the potato was introduced to Europe in the late 1500s.

Are there any halachic discussions by the rabbis at the time regarding the potato? E.g. with regards to Pesach.

Comment: With regards to pesach.. and what else? Consider editing that in—

Comment: Not a teshuva, but Chaye Adam considers them Kitniyos.

Comment: You will likely find this highly relevant and interesting: [The halachic adventures of the potato](https://ohr.edu/this_week/insights_into_halacha/5184)